# Attaching components so they move together

Tags: flutter, flame

Is it possible with flame components to attach them to other components so that their position is updated when the "parent" component moves?

I want to have a hitbox component and attached to it the player sprite, name tag and so on with an xy-offset.

Comment: did you find out how to add name tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any `PositionComponent` (most components in Flame inherit from `PositionComponent`) and add children to it.

So here for example we create a simple square which has two square children which move, scale and rotate together with the parent:

```
class Square extends PositionComponent {
  Square(Vector2 position, Vector2 size, {double angle = 0})
      : super(
          position: position,
          size: size,
          angle: angle,
        );
}

class ParentSquare extends Square with HasGameRef {
  ParentSquare(Vector2 position, Vector2 size) : super(position, size);

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    // All positions here are in relation to the parent's position
    add(Square(Vector2(100, 100), Vector2(50, 50), angle: 2));
    add(Square(Vector2(160, 100), Vector2(50, 50), angle: 3));
  }
}
```

An example can be seen [here](https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Components_Composability). (If you press `<>` you'll see the code for the example)